# Does it make sense to use a logistic regression model to ensemble probability models

Tags: logistic, ensemble-learning

Let $p_1$, $p_2$, ..., $p_k$ denote probabilities for an event with outcome 0 or 1 generated by $K$ distinct models. The linear ensemble of these probabilities is the problem of finding $\alpha_1$, ..., $\alpha_K$ with all $\alpha_i \geq 0$ and $\alpha_i + \dots + \alpha_K = 1$ in the following equation:
$$\hat{p} = \alpha_1 p_1 + \alpha_2 p_2 + \dots + \alpha_K p_K$$
such that the mean squared error between the outcome and $\hat{p}$ is minimised.

My question is whether you can use a logistic regression to combine these probability forecasts, e.g. the model:

$$\text{logit}(\hat{p}) = \alpha_1 \text{logit}(p_1) + \alpha_2 \text{logit}(p_2) + \dots + \alpha_K \text{logit}(p_K)$$

Are there any advantages or disadvantages for doing this? Is there any research into this? Also, should I include an intercept term in the regression?